# mysql_query to pdo conversion error on processing

Tags: php, pdo

I need help on converting mysql_query to PDO. The MySQL database is not updating when I edit columns. I've tried translating the following code:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
if($_GET['id'] and $_GET['data'])
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $data = $_GET['data'];
  $key = $_GET['key'];
  if(mysql_query("update information set $key='$data' where id='$id'"))
    echo 'success';
  }
} 
?>
```

Into this:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_GET))    
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    $key = $_GET['key'];
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO( DSN, DB_USR, DB_PWD );
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->query( "SET NAMES utf8" );
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        "UPDATE information
        SET
        key=:data where id=:id"
    );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':key', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e){
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
$pdo = null;
```

Comment: what you tried put that code too

Answer (score 0):

You used `:key` in your `bindValue()` call when it should be `:data`. You also need to put `$key` into the query (you can't use a placeholder for a column name, so this requires variable substitution).

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    "UPDATE information
    SET
    $key = :data where id=:id"
);
$stmt->bindValue( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->bindValue( ':data', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
```

You should validate `$key` before substituting it, to prevent SQL injection. Something like:

```
$allowed_keys = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
if (!in_array($key, $allowed_keys)) {
    die("Bad key $key");
}
```